# Multiple hosts each running a mutually exclusive service and public IP under a single domain name over WAN

Tags: domain-name-system, routing

Maybe the answer this is obvious, but suppose hypothetically that I manage 2 servers at *distinct* IP addresses routable on the public Internet (i.e. not on a LAN).  Server 1 runs a web server *only* and server 2 runs a ssh server *only*.  Can both servers co-exist under the same domain name: say "twoservices.org"?

- Server 1 : ssh server only on distinct IP pulbic address
- Server 2 : web server only on distinct IP pulbic address

So say that I want to connect to ssh server then I would

- ssh user@twoservices.org

and if I want to connect to web server then

- https://twoservices.org

Could this just be implemented with a DNS A record for each of the 2 IP's?
If not how can the above be implemented?

Comment: No, it cannot. Why are you thinking about doing something like this? Perhaps some alternate approach can be found.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, no.

a DNS record should point to only 1 IP or target host.
(or multiple in the case of DNS load balancing but that's another use case)
if you want to use the same DNS, both services should reside on the same host.

This is technically possible by using a relay (for example, configure your webhost serving https://twoservices.org as an ssh relay host and relay the ssh queries to the other SSH server.. but this is not exactly what you are asking for).